# How can I get the email [file] from Mac's mail application?

Tags: javascript, macos, drag-and-drop, email

So, I've got to implement a drag-and-drop operation from Mac's mail application into a website that I'm working on, after reading [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/safari/resources/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/DragAndDrop.html) and dissecting a few [HTML5 demos](https://bestvpn.org/html5demos/drag-anything/) I'm fairly well stuck.

I've already got the site properly processing .EML files; so everything would be great if I could, populate a file-input w/ the email's location. (Though, since it's a promised-file it [apparently] doesn't quite exist yet.)

I can get the list of contents sure, but I'm at a loss as to how to get the file from the `promised-file-url` or the (apparent) .EML file from `dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yc6durvwwa3xmrvw1gkdusm1044pxqyuha2pxsvw0e55bsmwca7d3sbwu`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use AppleScript to export the message(s) you need out of Mail.app?  There is an "archive" function in the ASD for Mail.app which will export, into an external file, pretty much all the fields you might want (identified in a pseudo-printf-like syntax).  Then you can slurp in the contents of that file however you want.  Probably the shortest distance between two points, and far more future-proof than trying to reverse engineer Mail's mailbox format.

Comment: Because a) they really want to be able to drag mail from apple's mail client, and b) they've mandated that the application be a web-based one.(I've never programmed on an Apple before in any case.)  Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Well, if you want the "exporting process" to be user driven through drags then yes, you have little choice but to make your own app (web based or otherwise) a drop target, which will require at least a good understanding of how D&D works on OS X. That said, you're going to find this one challenging given the two mandates since web apps don't have direct access to this kind of data and you're almost certainly going to have to have some sort of intermediate agent which both Mail.app and your web app talk to.  Heh.  Good luck? :)